# Tooltip positioning with raphael javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, dom-events

I'm having trouble making a tool tip appear next to a table coordinate created with raphael. I'm creating an application like that of seatgeek.com's interactive seating plan and I would like to be able to click on the right side table div (the right rectangular table info button on the right side of he page) and have the the tooltip initiate next to the table on the floor plan. It seems to be an issue with finding a good transformation to convert a tables position (Raphael's coordinates) into HTML position.

Also I can't programatically fire events in Raphael.

Any help on recreating the seatgeek interactive floorplan issues I'm having would be greatly appreciated.